# subset dataframe using unique values and return all rows for each unique value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subset

I'm trying to get a subset of a pandas dataframe based on unique values.

My overall dataframe has around 5k rows, where each row has an ID and text, each ID can have multiple text entries. The dataframe something looks like this:

```
Text | ID
bla    1
blu    1 
ble    1 
bli    3
bly    3
bln    2
blt    2
blk    2
blv    2
blw    6
```

What I would like to do is specify a number of unique ID's, such as 3 and return all the rows for it, where the end result would look like this:

```
    Text | ID 
    bli    3
    bly    3
    bln    2
    blt    2
    blk    2
    blv    2
    blw    6
```

It doesn't matter which IDs are returned, just that it is 3 ID's and if I rerun the method it is always the same 3 ID's.

I know how to select the unqiue values of a dataframe using this method:

```
unique = df['ID'].nunique()
```

but this is where my wisdom ends - any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `np.random.RandomState` with a seed for reproducibility, `np.random.choice` with `replace=False` to choose distinct elements and then `pd.Series.unique` to form the candidates and `pd.Series.isin` to mask the desired ID triplets:

```py
def get_unique_id_subset(df, k=3, seed=51):
    id_list = np.random.RandomState(seed).choice(df.ID.unique(), k, replace=False)
    return df[df.ID.isin(id_list)]
```

using:

```
>>> get_unique_id_subset(df)
  Text  ID
0  bla   1
1  blu   1
2  ble   1
3  bli   3
4  bly   3
9  blw   6

>>> get_unique_id_subset(df)  # same result as before
  Text  ID
0  bla   1
1  blu   1
2  ble   1
3  bli   3
4  bly   3
9  blw   6

>>> get_unique_id_subset(df, seed=19)  # changed the seed
  Text  ID
0  bla   1
1  blu   1
2  ble   1
5  bln   2
6  blt   2
7  blk   2
8  blv   2
9  blw   6

>>> get_unique_id_subset(df, seed=19)  # result consistent with the seed
  Text  ID
0  bla   1
1  blu   1
2  ble   1
5  bln   2
6  blt   2
7  blk   2
8  blv   2
9  blw   6
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't matter which 3 IDs, you could just get the first 3 with
`unique_3 = df['ID'].unique[:3]` and then select the rows with `df_id = df[df["ID"].isin(unique_3)]`.

Comment: hi there @luanpo - thank you for your suggestions, but the first line of code throws an invalid synatx error on .unique(:3) - is there another method to select three unqiue values?

Comment: Thank you @SergeBallesta.
It should work now.